# Transparent listview jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

How would one go about setting the listview items to be transparent, heres an example of it here, http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/8978/captureum.png

I have tried a few different methods so far but met with no success, And help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been working on this for a past hour, needed it myself ... well here is what I came with and it works

CSS rule:

```
.ui-listview .ui-btn-up-a {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

play with parameters in `rgba` to get your desired effect

and put in HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage" style="background: #000000 url('images/backgound.png') repeat;">
```

hope it helps,
regards

Comment: I got the effect I was looking for when I put the `background` line into `.ui-listview .ui-li.ui-field-contain`